# asp:EntityDataSource not working in VS2015

Tags: asp.net

I have inherited VS2010 project and updated to VS2015.

But when added to control I receive the following error.
EntityDataSource does not exist in namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls

This is really driving me crazy and hopefully there is simple explanation